# Intent filter behavior with web page redirect

Tags: android, android-intent, web, deep-linking, applinks

I have a question about the way that a declared `intent-filter` for some page `example.com/pageB` in `AndroidManifest.xml` would work in the following scenario:

1. There is a link in an email for a page `example.com/pageA` that is not declared in an `intent-filter`.
2. User clicks on the
   link
3. The link goes to a page that redirects to a new page `example.com/pageB`. The new
   page matches the `intent-filter` declared in the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`

Will the OS launch the app to handle the intent the same way it would have if the user directly clicked on a link to `example.com/pageB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS does not distinguish between the redirect to `example.com/pageB` and the user clicking on a link to that page so the intent filter works as expected.